# CSV file not exported in Rails 5 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, export-to-csv

In my Rails 5 application, I have an ajax put request that calls a bulk_create function that creates n number of records according to the parameter entered by the user (this works like a charm) and technically it should also generate a csv file using the data that have been just generated.

AJAX Call:

```
$('.bulk-button').on('click', function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/admin/coupons/bulk-create?number='+$('#bulk-number').val()
    });
});
```

In my Controller:

```
def bulk_create
    iterations = params[:number].to_i
    i = 0
    sequence = [('a'..'z')].map(&:to_a).flatten
    while i < iterations do
      name = (0...6).map { sequence[rand(sequence.length)] }.join
      Coupon.create(:name => name, :value => 10, :coupon_type => 'amount', :limit => 1, :expiration_date => Date.current + 365)
      i+=1
    end

    coupons = Coupon.order('created_at DESC').limit(iterations)

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to(admin_coupons_path) }
        format.csv { send_data coupons.to_csv }
    end
end
```

In my model:

```
def self.to_csv(options = {})
  desired_columns = ["name", "value"]
  CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
    csv << desired_columns
    all.each do |coupon|
      csv << coupon.attributes.values_at(*desired_columns)
    end
  end
end
```

I don't see any error generated in the console, yet no CSV file is being eported. Any guess?

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried using the .csv in the url? `/admin/coupons/bulk-create.csv?number=...`

Comment: First off, the `self.to_csv` defined in the model isn't what's being called when you call `coupons.to_csv` in the controller. The coupons in the controller is an ActiveRecord class and won't have access to Coupon class methods. In general, since the to_csv is doing more of a formatting/rendering type of operation, it shouldn't be defined on the model to begin with. You should create a new class (say, CouponsCsv?) and write the to_csv method on that. Better yet, there's probably a gem out there for exactly this problem. Also, as the above comment says, the request won't go through without .csv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be the Ajax. I've read in several posts that ajax indeed is what bothers the csv download. I have replaced the ajax call with a simple form_tag and it all worked out.

Answer (score 1):

**A bit about code clarity and style**

You have some complications in your code that don't need to be there : ranges can be used in a more direct way.

```
sequence = ('a'..'z').to_a
```

You can also use #sample to get a random element of an array which would give you :

```
sequence.sample
```

instead of

```
sequence[rand(sequence.length)]
```

A nice touch of `#inject` could help as well, it allows you to feed an object multiples time to avoid complicated syntaxes.
We would have thus :

```
(0...5).inject(""){ |coupon_code| coupon_code << sequence.sample }
```

**Another bit about your error**

My guess would be that the definition of the method `to_csv` is on the class Coupon itself and you are not calling it. Here your variable coupons is a collection of Coupon retrieved from database that has all the chances of behaving like an array. Let's see how an array handles `to_csv`.

```
[].to_csv # => "\n"
[Coupon.first, Coupon.first].to_csv
# => "#<Coupon:0x007f81ca4d2558>, #<Coupon:0x007f81ca4d2558>\n"
```

Array.to_csv seems to call to_s on each of its element and join them all with a csv separator. Here we got it, your method call is at the right place in the code and the `to_csv` does not raise an error because Array supports it!

Comment: That's a slight simplification since `Coupon.order('created_at DESC').limit(iterations)` really returns an ActiveRecord relation object and not an array, but otherwise a good answer. Also, to improve a bit further on the inject line, you can do `6.times.inject(""){ |coupon_code| coupon_code << sequence.sample }`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions on how to improve the code. Yeah indeed [].to_csv exist and I can see the csv response sent back in the response even though the file doesn't get downloaded.

@Gyoko - I tried also using some gem (specifically ascsv) and it generates more errors than ever and unfortunately there's very little documentation around

Comment: Also, I tried removing the self.to_csv method in my model and when testing I got: NoMethodError (undefined method `to_csv' for #<Coupon::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007ff9635f1ea0>
Did you mean?  to_s):

Which technically means that when I call the coupons.to_csv actually the self.to_csv is called.